# How do I display different names in the pop-up window by using the same xaml file?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to make a pop up window whereby by pressing check in button, a pop up will appear displaying the "check in" string. Check out button will do the exact same thing except that "check out" will be displayed instead. How can I do it in such a way that only one `PopUp.xaml` file is used instead of 2 similar ones.

Check in & Check out function:

```
private async void CheckOut_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new CheckOutPopUp(true));
    }

    private async void CheckIn_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new CheckInPopUp(true));
    }
```

CheckInPopUp.xaml/CheckOutPopUp.xaml:

```
<StackLayout
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Orientation="Vertical"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label
                Margin="20,50,20,10"
                FontSize="Large"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                Text="Check In"      //"Check Out" on CheckOutPopUp.xaml
                TextColor="White"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use [Xamarin.Forms Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers)  to achieve this just as Shaw mentioned.

If I understand correctly,do you want to show two different texts in the same PopupPage after clicking two buttons( `Check In` button and `Check Out` button),right?

If yes, you can refer to the following code:

In the first Page,there are two buttons(`check in` button and `check out` button)

```
    private async void CheckInButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new CheckPopUp(true));
    }

    private async void CheckOutButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new CheckPopUp(false));
    }
```

After clicking button `CheckInButton` and `CheckOutButton` ,page `CheckPopUp`  will display.

CheckPopUp.xaml.cs

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class CheckPopUp : PopupPage
{
    public bool IsCheckedIn { get; set; }
    public CheckPopUp(bool ischecked)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.IsCheckedIn = ischecked;

        BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

CheckPopUp.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<animations:PopupPage  xmlns:animations="http://rotorgames.com" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                       BackgroundColor="Green"
             x:Class="FrameRendererApp.CheckPopUp">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label  Text="Check In">
                <Label.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger
                       Binding="{Binding IsCheckedIn}"
                       TargetType="Label"
                       Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="Check Out" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Label.Triggers>
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</animations:PopupPage>
```

Comment: Thank you to both of you it worked beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, there is a boolean value for the current state "IsCheckedIn".

Then use [triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers) in xaml for different situation:

```
<Label ... Text="Check In">
    <Label.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger
            Binding="{Binding IsCheckedIn}"
            TargetType="Label"
            Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Checked Out" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Label.Triggers>
</Label>

<Button Clicked="Button_Clicked">
```

And define your event like this:

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(
        IsCheckedIn ? new CheckOutPopUp(true) : new CheckInPopUp(true));
}
```

If "IsCheckIn" is from your view model, then use the view model value like "viewModel.IsCheckIn" instead.